# gstreamer plugin library not linking against opencv shared object library - "undefined symbol" on Ubuntu

Tags: c, opencv, linker, shared-libraries, gstreamer

I have tried this for now whole weekend - Saturday/Sunday and Monday spending couple of hours but to no avail. I am following the gstreamer plugin writer's guide 
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/section-boiler-project-stamp.html. I had gstreamer-0.10 (sudo apt-get install method) and OpenCV 2.4 already installed before trying gstreamer plugin procedure. I am using default prefix (`/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10` for plugin testing during `./configure` prior to `sudo make && sudo make install`)

I managed to generate the boilerplate code. Now I added a cvcreateImage like

```
static GstFlowReturn
gst_cvtestfilter_chain (GstPad * pad, GstBuffer * buf)
{
Gstcvtestfilter *filter;
GstBuffer *outbuf;
IplImage* cvImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(cvwidth,cvheight),cvdepth, cvchannels);
.
.
}
```

If cvImage line is commented everything works smoothly. All tests are ok. Linking against OpenCV fails for some reason if I don't comment that line.

I modified the `makefile.am` to add OpenCV flags in src directory as

```
 # Note: plugindir is set in configure

##############################################################################
# TODO: change libgstcvtestfilter.la to something else, e.g. libmysomething.la     #
##############################################################################
plugin_LTLIBRARIES = libgstcvtestfilter.la

##############################################################################
# TODO: for the next set of variables, name the prefix if you named the .la, #
#  e.g. libmysomething.la => libmysomething_la_SOURCES                       #
#                            libmysomething_la_CFLAGS                        #
#                            libmysomething_la_LIBADD                        #
#                            libmysomething_la_LDFLAGS                       #
##############################################################################

# sources used to compile this plug-in
libgstcvtestfilter_la_SOURCES = gstcvtestfilter.c gstcvtestfilter.h

# compiler and linker flags used to compile this plugin, set in configure.ac
libgstcvtestfilter_la_CFLAGS = $(GST_CFLAGS) $(OPENCV_CFLAGS)
libgstcvtestfilter_la_LIBADD = $(GST_LIBS) $(OPENCV_LIBS)
libgstcvtestfilter_la_LDFLAGS = $(GST_PLUGIN_LDFLAGS) 
libgstcvtestfilter_la_LIBTOOLFLAGS = --tag=disable-static

# headers we need but don't want installed
noinst_HEADERS = gstcvtestfilter.h
```

I also modified `configure.ac` in the parent directory by adding

```
 dnl *** opencv ***
translit(dnm, m, l) AM_CONDITIONAL(USE_OPENCV, true)

  dnl we specify a max. version too because we set CV_NO_BACKWARD_COMPATIBILITY
  dnl and don't want the build to break when a new opencv version comes out.
  dnl Need to adjust this upwards once we know that our code compiles fine with
  dnl a new version and the no-backward-compatibility define. (There doesn't
  dnl seem to be a switch to suppress the warnings the cvcompat.h header
  dnl causes.)
  PKG_CHECK_MODULES(OPENCV, opencv >= 2.0.0 opencv <= 3.1.0 , [
    AC_PROG_CXX
    AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS
    OLD_CPPFLAGS=$CPPFLAGS
    CPPFLAGS=$OPENCV_CFLAGS
    AC_CHECK_HEADER(highgui.h, HAVE_HIGHGUI="yes", HAVE_HIGHGUI="no")
    AC_CHECK_HEADER(cvaux.h, HAVE_CVAUX="yes", HAVE_CVAUX="no")
    CPPFLAGS=$OLD_CPPFLAGS
    AC_LANG_C
    if test "x$HAVE_HIGHGUI" = "xno"; then
      AC_MSG_RESULT(highgui.h could not be found.)
      HAVE_OPENCV="no"
    elif test "x$HAVE_CVAUX" = "xno"; then
      AC_MSG_RESULT(cvaux.h could not be found.)
      HAVE_OPENCV="no"
    else
      HAVE_OPENCV="yes" 
      AC_SUBST(OPENCV_CFLAGS)
      AC_SUBST(OPENCV_LIBS)  
    fi
  ], [
    HAVE_OPENCV="no"
    AC_MSG_RESULT(no)
  ])
```

The compilation is fine - no errors.

Now when I run the plugin in pipeline I get this message

```
(gst-plugin-scanner:6396): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcvtestfilter.so': /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcvtestfilter.so: undefined symbol: cvCreateImage
```

So obviously my opencv situated in `/usr/local/lib` is not linking properly.

`sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc` contains

```
#Added By me
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH

#Added By me
PATH=$PATH:/opt/Xilinx/13.4/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin
export PATH

GST_PLUGIN_PATH=$GST_PLUGIN_PATH:/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10
export GST_PLUGIN_PATH
```

`sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf` contains

```
/usr/local/lib
```

`sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gst.conf` contains

```
/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10
```

`sudo ldconfig -v`

`sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` contains

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10
```

`ldd /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcvtestfilter.so` gives no opencv dependency which is strange

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77b6000)
libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0xb76b0000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb7661000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb7567000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb754c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb73a7000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xb73a2000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0xb7255000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb7228000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb721f000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb721a000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xb7213000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb71d7000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77b7000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb71c0000)
```

My OS is 32 bit 12.04 Ubuntu. If anyone can point me right direction I shall be grateful. Thanks.

**Update: (June 29 2012)**

Taking Cue from OpenCV experience I modified the `configure.ac` for OpenGL if someone is interested

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER(
    GL/gl.h,
    AC_DEFINE(
        [HAVE_OPENGL],
        [],
        Define to 1 if you have the <GL/gl.h> header file.
        )
        OPENGL_LIBS="$X_LIBS -lGL -lGLU -lpthread -lglut -lGLEW"
        opengl=yes,
    AC_MSG_WARN([*** no GL/gl.h -- opengl and SDL support disabled])
)
AC_SUBST(OPENGL_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(OPENGL_LIBS)


dnl AC_ARG_WITH(
dnl     opengl-cflags,
dnl     [  --with-opengl-cflags=PATH    Specify OpenGL cflags],
dnl     OPENGL_CFLAGS="$withval", OPENGL_CFLAGS="")
dnl AC_ARG_WITH(
dnl     opengl-libs,
dnl     [  --with-opengl-libs=PATH      Specify OpenGL libs (default is -lGL -lGLU -lpthread)],
dnl     OPENGL_LIBS="$withval", OPENGL_LIBS="-lGL -lGLU -lpthread -lglut -lGLEW")
dnl AC_SUBST(OPENGL_CFLAGS)
dnl AC_SUBST(OPENGL_LIBS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem consulting a friend with an ugly hack in `Makefile` in `src` directory.

**Solution I**

`LIBS =`  was empty so had to add OpenCV libraries there as follows.

```
LDFLAGS =
LIBOBJS =
LIBS = -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui # One may add more OpenCV libraries as needed here
LIBTOOL = $(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool
```

**Solution II (Better Solution Comes Along - But Still Ugly)**

Leave `LIBS =` empty but edit `OPENCV_LIBS=` in the `Makefile`.

In my case I had

`OPENCV_LIBS = /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so ...`

I replaced this line by

`OPENCV_LIBS = -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core ...` so on and so forth.

Replace this for all OpenCV libraries as needed in the `Makefile` at this line and it should work.

**Solution III (Preferred)** Change `Makefile.am` as follows and add all OpenCV libraries as necessary.

```
 # Note: plugindir is set in configure

##############################################################################
# TODO: change libgstcvtestfilter.la to something else, e.g. libmysomething.la     #
##############################################################################
plugin_LTLIBRARIES = libgstcvtestfilter.la

##############################################################################
# TODO: for the next set of variables, name the prefix if you named the .la, #
#  e.g. libmysomething.la => libmysomething_la_SOURCES                       #
#                            libmysomething_la_CFLAGS                        #
#                            libmysomething_la_LIBADD                        #
#                            libmysomething_la_LDFLAGS                       #
##############################################################################

# sources used to compile this plug-in
libgstcvtestfilter_la_SOURCES = gstcvtestfilter.c gstcvtestfilter.h

# compiler and linker flags used to compile this plugin, set in configure.ac
libgstcvtestfilter_la_CFLAGS = $(GST_CFLAGS) $(OPENCV_CFLAGS)
libgstcvtestfilter_la_LIBADD = $(GST_LIBS) $(OPENCV_LIBS) -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
libgstcvtestfilter_la_LDFLAGS = $(GST_PLUGIN_LDFLAGS) 
libgstcvtestfilter_la_LIBTOOLFLAGS = --tag=disable-static

# headers we need but don't want installed
noinst_HEADERS = gstcvtestfilter.h
```

**There is difference in the way opencv 2.3.1 and 2.4.0 is installed as can be seen from `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc`**

`/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc` file should look as follows: (The PC on which this gstreamer opencv plugin is installed works fine - Ubuntu 10.04)

```
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 2.3.1
Libs: -L${libdir} -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

instead of (The PC on which this gstreamer opencv plugin is installed needs Makefile modification - Ubuntu 12.04):

```
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 2.4.0
Libs:  ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_contrib.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_core.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_features2d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_flann.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_gpu.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_highgui.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_legacy.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ml.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_photo.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_stitching.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ts.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_video.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

I'll post better solution if I can find any.

Comment: Not really a great idea to modify `Makefile` in a project with autotools as there is good chance that the changes will be lost. Is your problem that after adding check for opencv & linking libraries in `Makefile.am` during build the linking is not done? Which version of opencv is installed on the system & what do you intend to use?

Comment: @another.anon.coward Totally agreed with you that Changes are lost when I run build system. Thats why I said `ugly hack` and is a temporary solution. I have two PCs one uses Opencv v2.3 (no modifications needed) and another uses Opencv v2.4 (modifications needed). See my updated solution post regards to *.pc files.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't quite get your problem here. Did you intend to say that due to different set of libraries being linked in different versions of opencv you are suspecting problem in linking?

Comment: Yes. That is my speculation because simply replacing e.g. `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so` with `-lopencv_core` links it correctly. Why would that happen? Please let me know the reason or if you suspect a different hypothesis.

Comment: It is quite strange to see the linker options being the name of the library in .pc file, but it generally does compile with the full path. What you could try out is, when you change LIBS to `-lopencv_core` and build, `make` will run `gcc` (most likely, not sure what CC & CXX you are compiling with) and build fine. Now try to run that `gcc` command by hand & replace `-lopencv_core` with full library path & see what is the outcome

Comment: I was using gcc hence used CC instead of CXX (g++). For hand compilation test(unrelated to Gstreamer) Something like `gcc -g opencv1.c -o opencv1 -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so` works fine instead of `gcc -g opencv1.c -o opencv1 $(pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12763/discussion-between-enthusiasticgeek-and-another-anon-coward)

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question was related to version 0.1 of GStreamer, but I've come across with a similar  error with GStreamer v1.4.5 when compiling from source, and with OpenCV 2.4.10.1 also compiled from source.

In my case, running `gst-inspect-1.0` would print the following message:

```
(gst-plugin-scanner:7485): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopencv.so': /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopencv.so: undefined symbol: cvCloneImage
...
...
Total count: 196 plugins (1 blacklist entry not shown), 1109 features
```

My solution was inspired in the solution 2 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11094953/4503525), but instead of changing source files just pass the OPENCV_LIBS  environment variable to autogen.sh.

```
OPENCV_LIBS="-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab" ./autogen.sh
```

You may need to adjust the libraries depending on the used build configuration.

Here is my output from `pkg-config --libs opencv`:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the configure run actualy find the opencv libraries? Check config.log. Also what exacly have you changed in the configure.ac part? As you noticed correctly the generated makefile is supposed to have those vars expanded.

Comment: See my updated post in the solution `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc` regarding how **opencv 2.3** and **opencv 2.4** differ in listing in `opencv.pc` file. I just added the block in configure.ac as posted in the question. config.log and Makefile in `src` directory both just reflects what is listed in `*.pc` file.